# How can I ged rid of semicolon or bracket error?

Tags: c#, json

I got the semicolon or bracket is expected error in below code, although the get set syntax is written properly. Where I missed one?

```
public string Serialized
        {
            get => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    return;
                }
                var jsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };
                var jData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApplicationPushNotificationSetting>(value, jsettings);
                IsEnabled = jData.IsEnabled;
                IsBackgroundQueueEnabled = jData.IsBackgroundQueueEnabled;
                DeliveryIntervalMinutes = jData.DeliveryIntervalMinutes;
                RetryAttempts = jData.RetryAttempts;
                RetryIntervalMinutes = jData.RetryIntervalMinutes;
                DeliveryProviderSettings = jData.DeliveryProviderSettings;
                AntiNoiseSettings = jData.AntiNoiseSettings;
                BroadcastSettings = jData.BroadcastSettings;
            };
        }
```

Comment: You should be getting an error I suppose. If so, what was the error.

Comment: @Nair Semicolon or Bracket is expected error.

Comment: Remove the `;` on the scope of `set { ... };` to `set { ... }`.

Comment: @FrankNielsen I did that too, still no chance. Visual studio throws the same error while debugging.

Comment: It is possible to Debug a previous build. So (re)build your project until no errors occur - and then start debugging.

Comment: What version of c# are you using?

Comment: Is it possible that you cannot mix expression bodied getter with a statement bodied setter?

Comment: @CodingFreak - *I did that too, still no chance.* - then can you please share a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?  I tried pasting your code fragment into a fiddle and there were many compilation errors due to undefined symbols, e.g. `The name 'IsEnabled' does not exist in the current context`.  That being said, eliminating the `;` after the closing curly brace of the setter did eliminate a `Semicolon after method or accessor block is not valid` error, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/UVeIL0.

Comment: One note: your code has a stack overflow.  Unless you mark `Serialized` with `[JsonIgnore]` you will get an infinite recursion while serializing.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter has a semicolon at the end. You don’t need that.

Comment: So why the visual studio keeps giving the error while running the app?

Comment: Please look at the set accessor, which has a ; at the end and hence it might be complaining. Remove that ; and try.

Comment: I did it, no chance. Still the same